# Changing scroll range for mouse wheel

Tags: front-end, dynamic

Is there a possibility to change the range for scrolling with the mouse wheel in *Mathematica*? In `ScrollingOptions` I couldn't find such an option. I played around with the options, but couldn't find a configuration that would solve my problem.

Right now scrolling with the mouse wheel scrolls down for about 3/4 of one page, but I want to scroll lines not pages. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What OS are you on? What option combinations have you tried so far with `ScrollingOptions`?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. I am using KDE. I don't think that I can write down the options I tried, since I tried basically all combinations in Scrolling Options.